Custom alerts sent to Alertmanager not showing up in Grafana
I am currently using a version of the kube-prometheus-stack Helm chart to deploy Grafana, Prometheus and Alertmanager.
I made a Go program to send custom alerts to Alertmanager (this feature will be used in the future). It looks like this:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type Alert struct {
    Status         string                `json:"status"`
    Labels         map[string]string     `json:"labels"`
    Annotations    map[string]string     `json:"annotations"`
    EndsAt         string                `json:"endsAt"`
}

func main() {
    url := "http://alertmanager_url:9093/api/v1/alerts"

    alert := []Alert{
        {
            Status: "firing",
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "alertname": "testAlert",
                "severity": "critical",
            },
            Annotations: map[string]string{
                "summary": "This is a test alert.",
            },
            EndsAt: "2023-03-21T00:10:53-03:00",
        },
    }

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(alert)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Println(err)
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewReader(jsonData))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}

This works fine, I see my alerts popping up in Alertmanager. However, in Grafana, I can see all the standard alerts firing, but not my test alerts.
Is there something wrong with my Go program, or am I missing something? I can provide more information if needed.

How (and where) does Grafana show other alerts, exactly?

I created a dashboard with the alert_list plugin so all the alerts I have show up there

As far as I can tell, this plugin only shows alerts of the Grafana itself, not retrieving them from alertmanager. So everything seems to work as expected.

As of now, the plugin retrieves all the alerts from Alertmanager generated by a Prometheus rule, but not the custom ones I send directly to Alertmanager's API.

I suspect (!?) that Grafana is pulling alert data from Prometheus not from AlertManager. You would need to have Prometheus originate alerts for them to be caught by Grafana.
Your code doesn't compile and you may want to switch to v2.
See Sending Alerts.
You should use api/v2 (defined here)
Try this:

I've preserved the bulk of your code
This variant uses /api/v2
The message (Alerts) differs slightly
Go JSON marshaling permits conversion to|from time.Time (see StartsAt and EndsAt)
Your TLS client was created incorrectly

package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log/slog"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Alert struct {
    StartsAt     time.Time         `json:"startsAt"`
    EndsAt       time.Time         `json:"endsAt"`
    Annotations  map[string]string `json:"annotations"`
    Labels       map[string]string `json:"labels"`
    GeneratorURL string            `json:"generatorURL"`
}

var (
    endpoint = flag.String(
        "endpoint",
        "0.0.0.0:9093",
        "Endpoint of the AlertManager",
    )
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    startAt := time.Now()
    endsAt := startAt.Add(24 * time.Hour)

    alert := []Alert{
        {
            StartsAt: startAt,
            EndsAt:   endsAt,
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "alertname": "testAlert",
                "severity":  "critical",
            },
            Annotations: map[string]string{
                "summary": "This is a test alert.",
            },
            GeneratorURL: "http://foo/test",
        },
    }

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(alert)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("Unable to marshal", "err", err)
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
            },
        },
    }

    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s/api/v2/alerts", *endpoint)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewReader(jsonData))
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to create request",
            "err", err,
        )
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to invoke request",
            "err", err,
        )
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to read response body",
            "err", err,
        )
    }

    slog.Info(string(body))
}

And:
ENDPOINT="..."

go run . --endpoint=${ENDPOINT}

And:
curl \
--silent ${ENDPOINT}/api/v2/alerts \
| jq -r .

[
  {
    "annotations": {
      "summary": "This is a test alert."
    },
    "endsAt": "2024-04-12T15:30:41.521-07:00",
    "fingerprint": "a6fe2270a4e28dea",
    "receivers": [
      {
        "name": "web.hook"
      }
    ],
    "startsAt": "2024-04-11T15:30:41.521-07:00",
    "status": {
      "inhibitedBy": [],
      "silencedBy": [],
      "state": "active"
    },
    "updatedAt": "2024-04-11T22:30:44.446Z",
    "generatorURL": "http://foo/test",
    "labels": {
      "alertname": "testAlert",
      "severity": "critical"
    }
  }
]


Thanks a lot, your code is much cleaner than mine :P I don't fully get your explanation about Prometheus originating alerts. What I get is that Prometheus and Alertmanager are both configured as datasources in Grafana, and I would expect my alerts to show up in Grafana even if they are not triggerd by a Prometheus rule. Or am I missing something?

I Googled your issue and I think I am incorrect. I think Grafana does (as you suspect) use Alertmanager for its source of alerts (not Prometheus as I suspected). So I'm also unsure why it isn't finding alerts created by the code.

(Clearly) I don't use Grafana for this integration but I found this page on Grafana's documentation to Add an external Alertmanager

In your example, your alert endsAt a date in 2023 and so I wonder whether this was why your alerts weren't being discovered (too old). Have you tried generating a current alert (i.e. endsAt > now)? Also, I don't fully understand why, but the documentation says "Clients are expected to continuously re-send alerts as long as they are still active (usually on the order of 30 seconds to 3 minutes). Clients can push a list of alerts to Alertmanager via a POST request."

I have tried sending alerts > now. The thing is, all my alerts show up in the Alertmanager UI, but not in Grafana. I did the setup as suggested in the page you mentionned, but it didn't change anything. I don't think it's a client-related problem.

I also tried this with Grafana and I receive the alrerts from AlertManager. I'm unable to repro your issue so can't help.
